# Quartz Core. Solid colored rectangle and gradient colored circle on the same path

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

I believe subj is possible. If yes, then how to do it?
If not, then how to set specific color on the specific path?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Ok. Deleted confusing part of message.

Comment: Perhaps include an image of what you want to achieve? A gradient coloured circle is not drawn with a path, a path is used to clip the context and then the gradient is drawn separately. Think of a path as drawn in a single action, with a single colour - so your answer to your question _title_ is no, but I don't know what the rest of your question means.

Comment: @jrturton, if you post your message as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gradient coloured circle is not drawn with a path, a path is used to clip the context and then the gradient is drawn separately. Think of a path as drawn in a single action, with a single colour - so your answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what you're looking for since the code you posted uses the rects for clipping, but you're talking about coloring them each differently. But how about something like this:

```
CGContextSetFillColor (cx, fillColor0);
CGContextFillRect (cx, CGRectMake (x0, y0, w0, h0));
CGContextSetFillColor (cx, fillColor1);
CGContextFillRect (cx, CGRectMake (x1, y1, w1, h1));
CGContextSetFillColor (cx, fillColor2);
CGContextFillRect (cx, CGRectMake (x2, y2, w2, h2));
CGContextSetFillColor (cx, fillColor3);
CGContextFillRect (cx, CGRectMake (x3, y3, w3, h3));
CGContextRadialGradient (...etc...);
```

If this is way off from what you're looking for, clarify what it is you want.

Comment: The main goal is to do what your code above doing, but in the path.
Maybe I don't understand paths?